# CSS link tags works but not @import

Tags: html, css, sass, webforms

Got a quick question, just wondering why my  stylesheet reference is working but not my @import tag using scss. How come when I use a  stylesheet reference in my header.php tag, it's working but it's not working when being imported via scss.

**File**: header.php

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nanum+Gothic&display=swap&subset=korean" rel="stylesheet">
```

**File**: _variables.scss

```
// Korean font family based on local team request
$korean: $whitney, 'Nanum Gothic', sans-serif;
```

**Result**: Works perfectly using link
[image]

---

**File**: _variables.scss

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nanum+Gothic&display=swap&subset=korean');

// Korean font family based on local team request
$korean: $whitney, 'Nanum Gothic', sans-serif;
```

**Result**: Not working
[image]

Is there a way around the @import? I would really want to use @import or unless  can be used with scss.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try [PostCSS Import URL Plugin](https://github.com/unlight/postcss-import-url) or [SCSS Loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader). It will pull the scss into your code. other-vice Scss does not compile from remote file